# Trello: Can I see the history per day of the number of card in a list?

Tags: trello

I would like to know if there is any "simple" way to trace, in a calendar for a given Trello project board, the day by day history number of cards in a given list.

I would need to see the Todo list history with just the number of card for everyday.

Is there any plugin or tool for doing that ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way:

1. Invite user "butlerbot" to your board. It will automatically create a "Butler" list in your board.
2. In the "Butler" list, add a card with the following title:

   every day at 6pm, count the cards in list "X"

Every day, the bot will automatically post a comment on that same card with the number of cards in the list. If your timezone is not U.S. Eastern, you also need to add another card with a title such as:

```
my timezone is Europe/London
```

A list of all the timezones supported by the bot can be found here: [Timezones](https://trello.com/c/7Qd0SKIe/41-timezones)

There's a ton of other stuff the bot can do, check it out here: [Butler Bot for Trello](https://trello.com/b/2dLsEE9t/butlerbot-for-trello). You can also contact the author and request support in that same board. Disclosure: I'm the author.